# JavaScript Code unable to reuse for 2nd quiz

Tags: javascript

```js
var question001 = ["Q1: How do you say Yellow in Swedish?"];
var choises001 = ["<input onclick=incorrect001() name=button001 type=radio />Röd<br/> <input onclick=correct001() name=button001 type=radio />Gul<br/> <input onclick=incorrect001() name=button001 type=radio />Vit<br />"];

var question002 = ["Q2: How do you say Thursday in Swedish"];
var choises002 = ["<input onclick=incorrect002() name=button002 type=radio />Onsdag<br/> <input onclick=incorrect002() name=button002 type=radio />Sundag<br/> <input onclick=correct002() name=button002 type=radio />Torsdag<br />"];

var question003 = ["Q3: How do you say It Is Nine O'Clock in Swedish"];
var choises003 = ["<input onclick=correct003() name=button003 type=radio />Klockan är nio<br/> <input onclick=incorrect003() name=button003 type=radio />Klockan är halv två<br/> <input onclick=incorrect003() name=button003 type=radio />Klockan är ett<br />"];

var question004 = ["Q4: What is Hello in Swedish?"];
var choises004 = ["<input onclick=correct004() name=button004 type=radio />Hej<br/> <input onclick=incorrect004() name=button004 type=radio />Hej då<br/> <input onclick=incorrect004() name=button004 type=radio />Välkommen<br />"];

var question005 = ["Q5: What is Thirteen in Swedish?"]
var choises005 = ["<input onclick=incorrect005() name=button005 type=radio />ett<br/> <input onclick=correct005() name=button005 type=radio />tretton<br/> <input onclick=incorrect005() name=button005 type=radio />tjugo<br />"];

var question006 = ["Q6: What is the 3rd letter in the Swedish Alphabet?"];
var choises006 = ["<input onclick=incorrect006() name=button006 type=radio />F<br/> <input onclick=correct006() name=button006 type=radio />C<br/> <input onclick=incorrect006() name=button006 type=radio />Z<br />"];

var question007 = ["Q7: Which letters are different from the English Alphabet?"];
var choises007 = ["<input onclick=correct007() name=button007 type=radio />Å, Ä, Ö<br/> <input onclick=incorrect007() name=button007 type=radio />R, Z, Q<br/> <input onclick=incorrect007() name=button007 type=radio />P, L, K<br />"];

var question008 = ["Q8: How do you ask someone's Name in Swedish?"];
var choises008 = ["<input onclick=incorrect008() name=button008 type=radio />Hur mår du?<br/> <input onclick=correct008() name=button008 type=radio />Vad heter du?<br/> <input onclick=incorrect008() name=button008 type=radio />Bra, tack<br />"];

var question009 = ["Q9: How do you say Several Forks in Swedish?"];
var choises009 = ["<input onclick=incorrect009() name=button009 type=radio />Flera lampor<br/> <input onclick=correct009() name=button009 type=radio />Flera gafflar<br/> <input onclick=incorrect009() name=button009 type=radio />En gaffel<br />"];

var question010 = ["Q10: How do you say June in Swedish?"];
var choises010 = ["<input onclick=incorrect010() name=button0010 type=radio />September<br/> <input onclick=incorrect010() name=button010 type=radio />Blå<br/> <input onclick=correct010() name=button010 type=radio />Juni<br />"];

var a;
var b;
var d;
var e;
var f;
var g;
var h;
var i;
var j;
var k;
var c;


window.onload = function(){
  a = 0;
message001.innerHTML = question001;
options001.innerHTML = choises001;
click001.innerHTML = "<button onclick=set002()>Submit</button";                                  
}

function correct001() {
  a = 1;
}

function incorrect001(){
  a = 0;

}
//////
function set002(){
  b = 0;
  message001.innerHTML = question002;
  options001.innerHTML = choises002;
  click001.innerHTML = "<button onclick=set003()>Next</button>";
}

function correct002(){
  b = 1;
}

function incorrect002(){
  b = 0;
}
//////
function set003(){
  d = 0;
  message001.innerHTML = question003;
  options001.innerHTML = choises003;
  click001.innerHTML = "<button onclick=set004()>Next</button>";
}

function correct003(){
  d = 1;
}

function incorrect003(){
  d = 0;
}

//////
function set004(){
  e = 0;
  message001.innerHTML = question004;
  options001.innerHTML = choises004;
  click001.innerHTML = "<button onclick=set005()>Next</button>";
}

function correct004(){
  e = 1;
}

function incorrect004(){
  e = 0;
}
//////
function set005(){
  f = 0;
  message001.innerHTML = question005;
  options001.innerHTML = choises005;
  click001.innerHTML = "<button onclick=set006()>Next</button>";
}

function correct005(){
  f = 1;
}

function incorrect005(){
  f = 0;
}

//////
function set006(){
  g = 0;
  message001.innerHTML = question006;
  options001.innerHTML = choises006;
  click001.innerHTML = "<button onclick=set007()>Next</button>";
}

function correct006(){
  g = 1;
}

function incorrect006(){
  g = 0;
}
//////

function set007(){
  h = 0;
  message001.innerHTML = question007;
  options001.innerHTML = choises007;
  click001.innerHTML = "<button onclick=set008()>Next</button>";
}

function correct007(){
  h = 1;
}

function incorrect007(){
  h = 0;
}

//////
function set008(){
  i = 0;
  message001.innerHTML = question008;
  options001.innerHTML = choises008;
  click001.innerHTML = "<button onclick=set009()>Next</button>";
}

function correct008(){
  i = 1;
}

function incorrect008(){
  i = 0;
}

//////

function set009(){
  j = 0;
  message001.innerHTML = question009;
  options001.innerHTML = choises009;
  click001.innerHTML = "<button onclick=set010()>Next</button>";
}

function correct009(){
  j = 1;
}

function incorrect009(){
  j = 0;
}

//////

function set010(){
  k = 0;
  message001.innerHTML = question010;
  options001.innerHTML = choises010;
  click001.innerHTML = "<button onclick=result001()>Score</button>";
}


function correct010(){
  k = 1;
}

function incorrect010(){
  k = 0;
}

//////
function result001(){
  c = a + b + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k;
  message001.innerHTML = "End of Quiz";
  options001.innerHTML = "";
  click001.innerHTML = "";
  comment001.innerHTML = "Congratulations! Your score is: " + c;
  comment002.innerHTML = "If you scored lower than 2, please keep practising";
  
}

///////////////////////////////////START 2ND QUIZ/////////////////


var question011 = ["Q11: Translate: I am a woman"];
var choises011 = ["<input onclick=incorrect011() name=button011 type=radio />Hon är min granne<br/> <input onclick=correct011() name=button011 type=radio />Jag är en kvinna<br/> <input onclick=incorrect011() name=button011 type=radio />Han går till skolan<br />"];

var question012 = ["Q12: Translate: We"];
var choises012 = ["<input onclick=incorrect012() name=button012 type=radio />Jag<br/> <input onclick=incorrect012() name=button012 type=radio />Ni<br/> <input onclick=correct012() name=button012 type=radio />Vi<br />"];

var question013 = ["Q13: Translate: Where (to)..?"];
var choises013 = ["<input onclick=correct013() name=button013 type=radio />Vart..?<br/> <input onclick=incorrect013() name=button013 type=radio />Var..?<br/> <input onclick=incorrect013() name=button013 type=radio />Varifrån..?<br />"];

var question014 = ["Q14: Translate: How much is that car?"];
var choises014 = ["<input onclick=correct014() name=button014 type=radio />Hur mycket är den bilen?<br/> <input onclick=incorrect014() name=button014 type=radio />När ska du gå i skolan?<br/> <input onclick=incorrect014() name=button014 type=radio />Hur många bilar har du?<br />"];

var question015 = ["Q15: Translate: At work."];
var choises015 = ["<input onclick=incorrect015() name=button015 type=radio />I kyrkan.<br/> <input onclick=correct015() name=button015 type=radio />På arbetet.<br/> <input onclick=incorrect015() name=button015 type=radio />På banken.<br />"];

var question016 = ["Q16: Translate: The lamp stands on the bureau."];
var choises016 = ["<input onclick=incorrect016() name=button016 type=radio />Lampan hänger i taket.<br/> <input onclick=correct016() name=button016 type=radio />Lampan står på byrån<br/> <input onclick=incorrect016() name=button016 type=radio />Lampan står på golvet.<br />"];

var question017 = ["Q17: Translate: Cry, Crying, Cried."];
var choises017 = ["<input onclick=correct017() name=button017 type=radio />Gråta, Gråter, Grät.<br/> <input onclick=incorrect017() name=button017 type=radio />Blåsa, Blåser, Blåste<br/> <input onclick=incorrect017() name=button017 type=radio />Ramla, Ramlar, Ramlade.<br />"];

var question018 = ["Q18: En or Ett - An Apple"];
var choises018 = ["<input onclick=incorrect018() name=button018 type=radio />En äpple<br/> <input onclick=correct018() name=button018 type=radio />Ett äpple<br/> <input onclick=incorrect018() name=button018 type=radio />Äpplena<br />"];

var question019 = ["Q19: Translate: The painting"];
var choises019 = ["<input onclick=incorrect019() name=button019 type=radio />En tavla<br/> <input onclick=correct019() name=button019 type=radio />Tavlan<br/> <input onclick=incorrect019() name=button019 type=radio />Tavlor<br />"];

var question020 = ["Q20: Translate: The eyes"];
var choises020 = ["<input onclick=incorrect020() name=button020 type=radio />Ögat<br/> <input onclick=incorrect020() name=button020 type=radio />Öga<br/> <input onclick=correct020() name=button020 type=radio />Ögonen<br />"];

var l;
var m;
var o;
var p;
var q;
var r;
var s;
var t;
var u;
var v;
var n;
///////////
window.onload = function(){
  l = 0;
message003.innerHTML = question011;
options003.innerHTML = choises011;
click003.innerHTML = "<button onclick= set012()>Submit</button";                                  
}

function correct011() {
  l = 1;
}

function incorrect011(){
  l = 0;

}
//////
function set012(){
  m = 0;
  message003.innerHTML = question012;
  options003.innerHTML = choises012;
  click003.innerHTML = "<button onclick=set013()>Next</button>";
}

function correct012(){
  m = 1;
}

function incorrect012(){
  m = 0;
}
//////
function set013(){
  o = 0;
  message003.innerHTML = question013;
  options003.innerHTML = choises013;
  click003.innerHTML = "<button onclick=set014()>Next</button>";
}

function correct013(){
  o = 1;
}

function incorrect013(){
  o = 0;
}

//////
function set014(){
  p = 0;
  message003.innerHTML = question014;
  options003.innerHTML = choises014;
  click003.innerHTML = "<button onclick=set015()>Next</button>";
}

function correct014(){
  p = 1;
}

function incorrect014(){
  p = 0;
}
//////
function set015(){
  q = 0;
  message003.innerHTML = question015;
  options003.innerHTML = choises015;
  click003.innerHTML = "<button onclick=set016()>Next</button>";
}

function correct015(){
  q = 1;
}

function incorrect015(){
  q = 0;
}

//////
function set016(){
  r = 0;
  message003.innerHTML = question016;
  options003.innerHTML = choises016;
  click003.innerHTML = "<button onclick=set017()>Next</button>";
}

function correct016(){
  r = 1;
}

function incorrect016(){
  r = 0;
}
//////

function set017(){
  s = 0;
  message003.innerHTML = question017;
  options003.innerHTML = choises017;
  click003.innerHTML = "<button onclick=set018()>Next</button>";
}

function correct017(){
  s = 1;
}

function incorrect017(){
  s = 0;
}

//////
function set018(){
  t = 0;
  message003.innerHTML = question018;
  options003.innerHTML = choises018;
  click003.innerHTML = "<button onclick=set019()>Next</button>";
}

function correct018(){
  t = 1;
}

function incorrect018(){
  t = 0;
}

//////

function set019(){
  u = 0;
  message003.innerHTML = question019;
  options003.innerHTML = choises019;
  click003.innerHTML = "<button onclick=set020()>Next</button>";
}

function correct019(){
  u = 1;
}

function incorrect019(){
  u = 0;
}

//////

function set020(){
  v = 0;
  message003.innerHTML = question020;
  options003.innerHTML = choises020;
  click003.innerHTML = "<button onclick=result0003()>Score</button>";
}


function correct020(){
  v = 1;
}

function incorrect020(){
  v = 0;
}

//////
function result0003(){
  n = l + m + o + p + q + r + s + t + u + v;
  message003.innerHTML = "End of Quiz";
  options003.innerHTML = "";
  click003.innerHTML = "";
  comment003.innerHTML = "Congratulations! Your score is: " + n;
  comment004.innerHTML = "If you scored lower than 2, please keep practising";  
}
```

```css
/* Start Quiz*/
#frame001 {
    height:270px;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: #E9CFEC;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#center001{
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
    font-size: 15px;
}

h3{
    background: #FAFAFA;
}

/* End Quiz*/


/* Start Quiz 2*/
#frame003 {
    height:270px;
    width: 350px;
    background-color: #E9CFEC;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;

  }

#center003{
    text-align: left;
    color: black;
    font-size: 15px;
}
/* End Quiz 2*/
```

```html
<div id="frame001">
    <div id="center001">
        <h3>Swedish Quiz  - Lessons 1 - 8</h3>
       <hr />
       <p id="message001"></p>
       <p id="options001"></p>
       <p id="click001"></p>
       <p id="comment001"></p>
       <p id="comment002"></p>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="frame003">
    <div id="center003">
        <h3>Swedish Quiz  - Lessons 9 - 16</h3>
       <hr />
       <p id="message003"></p>
       <p id="options003"></p>
       <p id="click003"></p>
       <p id="comment003"></p>
       <p id="comment004"></p>
</div>
```

If I remove the 2nd quiz the original quiz is working, If I remove the 1st quiz to 2nd one is working. I cannot get them to work together despite given them unique numbers-names´. As well I have to put a lot of
to keep them below each other. Cannot get them beside each other, nor inside the body border. See below. I hope someone can help me out. I am still new at coding and Javascript

Comment: there are so much code posted. can you provide a small sample to illustrate the problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) rather than posting all of your code, much of which (e.g. CSS) is not relevant to your problem.

Comment: You cannot have multiple `window.onload = ...`. Just like doing `x = 1; x = 2;` You are overwriting the previous one(s), so only the last `onload` will execute. Instead, use `window.addEventListener('load', function() {...});` which can be added multiple times. But your biggest problem here is that you duplicated so much code. It's impossible to maintain, you must be going crazy :) Whenever you are tempted to copy/paste code with only a slight difference, instead of doing that, you should refactor it to make it work with multiple instances. It'll be easier to maintain, and way more readable

Comment: If you run the code you see that the 1st quiz is empty. If I remove that code the 1st one is back and working. Eventhough I have split the code, I cannot get them both working on its own,

Comment: It seems like a lot of code, but each quiz contain 10 questions with each 3 possible answers.

Comment: But you are giving yourself a veeeeery hard time by duplicating functions and having them named `001`, `002`, etc. You should never ever have to do that. I'm working on a refactor of your code, I'm sure you'll understand the benefits (It will take some time, maybe 20 - 30 minutes, and I'll post an answer)

Comment: Thanks Blex, the window.addEventListener('load', function() {...}); solved the issue :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest problem with your code is that you duplicated a lot of it. Whenever you are tempted to copy/paste some code and make only slight changes to it, it's always good to start refactoring.

With the example below, you'll notice that there is only one version of the code. You could have a 1000 quizzes in the same page, the code wouldn't need to change, nothing needs to be duplicated. The only thing you would need to do is add the quiz data into the `quizzes` variable. The script will take care of everything else. And if you would like to change the behavior of the quizzes, you would only need to do it in a single place. That's a great benefit!

You don't "have to" use this, but please take a look at how it is structured. If there's something unclear, don't hesitate to comment:

```js
var quizzes = [
  {
    name: "Swedish Quiz  - Lessons 1 - 8",
    questions: [
      {
        text: "How do you say Yellow in Swedish?",
        image: "https://media0.giphy.com/media/fWlesbav1qMk8/giphy.gif",
        choices: [
          { text: "Röd", correct: false },
          { text: "Gul", correct: true },
          { text: "Vit", correct: false },
        ],
      },
      {
        text: "How do you say Thursday in Swedish",
        image: "https://media2.giphy.com/media/ce280BjADCmsfgps4t/giphy.gif",
        choices: [
          { text: "Onsdag", correct: false },
          { text: "Sundag", correct: false },
          { text: "Torsdag", correct: true },
        ],
      },
      {
        text: "How do you say It Is Nine O'Clock in Swedish",
        image: "https://media2.giphy.com/media/kbGuEmD7AYhqM/giphy.gif",
        choices: [
          { text: "Klockan är nio", correct: true },
          { text: "Klockan är halv två", correct: false },
          { text: "Klockan är ett", correct: false },
        ],
      },
      {
        text: "What is Hello in Swedish?",
        image: "https://media2.giphy.com/media/xT9IgG50Fb7Mi0prBC/giphy.gif",
        choices: [
          { text: "Hej", correct: true },
          { text: "Hej då", correct: false },
          { text: "Välkommen", correct: false },
        ],
      },
      {
        text: "What is Thirteen in Swedish?",
        image: "https://media1.giphy.com/media/BMVJe4c50A6XChmLRe/giphy.gif",
        choices: [
          { text: "ett", correct: false },
          { text: "tretton", correct: true },
          { text: "tjugo", correct: false },
        ],
      },
      {
        text: "What is the 3rd letter in the Swedish Alphabet?",
        image: "https://media0.giphy.com/media/3o7TKTDn976rzVgky4/giphy.gif",
        choices: [
          { text: "F", correct: false },
          { text: "C", correct: true },
          { text: "Z", correct: false },
        ],
      },
      {
        text: "Which letters are different from the English Alphabet?",
        image: "https://media0.giphy.com/media/W0VNVSm24um4yLUYfY/giphy.gif",
        choices: [
          { text: "Å, Ä, Ö", correct: true },
          { text: "R, Z, Q", correct: false },
          { text: "P, L, K", correct: false },
        ],
      },
      {
        text: "How do you ask someone's Name in Swedish?",
        image: "https://media2.giphy.com/media/fGObGrJxGSugQ9rXQK/giphy.gif",
        choices: [
          { text: "Hur mår du?", correct: false },
          { text: "Vad heter du?", correct: true },
          { text: "Bra, tack", correct: false },
        ],
      },
      {
        text: "How do you say Several Forks in Swedish?",
        image: "https://media1.giphy.com/media/13z1xhUK1ogrde/giphy.gif",
        choices: [
          { text: "Flera lampor", correct: false },
          { text: "Flera gafflar", correct: true },
          { text: "En gaffel", correct: false },
        ],
      },
      {
        text: "How do you say June in Swedish?",
        image: "https://media1.giphy.com/media/1wR4V5Y0Wqjn0Jgh2k/giphy.gif",
        choices: [
          { text: "September", correct: false },
          { text: "Blå", correct: false },
          { text: "Juni", correct: true },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: "Swedish Quiz  - Lessons 9 - 16",
    questions: [
      {
        text: "How do you say Yellow in Swedish?",
        choices: [
          { text: "Röd", correct: false },
          { text: "Gul", correct: true },
          { text: "Vit", correct: false },
        ],
      },
      {
        text: "How do you say Thursday in Swedish",
        choices: [
          { text: "Onsdag", correct: false },
          { text: "Sundag", correct: false },
          { text: "Torsdag", correct: true },
        ],
      },
      {
        text: "How do you say It Is Nine O'Clock in Swedish",
        choices: [
          { text: "Klockan är nio", correct: true },
          { text: "Klockan är halv två", correct: false },
          { text: "Klockan är ett", correct: false },
        ],
      },
      {
        text: "What is Hello in Swedish?",
        choices: [
          { text: "Hej", correct: true },
          { text: "Hej då", correct: false },
          { text: "Välkommen", correct: false },
        ],
      },
      {
        text: "What is Thirteen in Swedish?",
        choices: [
          { text: "ett", correct: false },
          { text: "tretton", correct: true },
          { text: "tjugo", correct: false },
        ],
      },
      {
        text: "What is the 3rd letter in the Swedish Alphabet?",
        choices: [
          { text: "F", correct: false },
          { text: "C", correct: true },
          { text: "Z", correct: false },
        ],
      },
      {
        text: "Which letters are different from the English Alphabet?",
        choices: [
          { text: "Å, Ä, Ö", correct: true },
          { text: "R, Z, Q", correct: false },
          { text: "P, L, K", correct: false },
        ],
      },
      {
        text: "How do you ask someone's Name in Swedish?",
        choices: [
          { text: "Hur mår du?", correct: false },
          { text: "Vad heter du?", correct: true },
          { text: "Bra, tack", correct: false },
        ],
      },
      {
        text: "How do you say Several Forks in Swedish?",
        choices: [
          { text: "Flera lampor", correct: false },
          { text: "Flera gafflar", correct: true },
          { text: "En gaffel", correct: false },
        ],
      },
      {
        text: "How do you say June in Swedish?",
        choices: [
          { text: "September", correct: false },
          { text: "Blå", correct: false },
          { text: "Juni", correct: true },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

// When the document is ready
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var $container = document.getElementById('container');
  // Initialize each quiz into the container
  quizzes.forEach(function(quiz) { initQuiz(quiz, $container); });
});

function initQuiz(quiz, $container) {
  // DOM elements
  var $dom = initDOM(quiz, $container),
  // Current question index (starts at 0)
      num = 0,
      score = 0;
  
  nextScreen();
  
  function nextScreen() {
    if (num < quiz.questions.length) {
      displayQuestion();
    } else {
      displayEndResult();
    }
  }
  
  function displayQuestion() {
    clearDisplayArea();
    var question = quiz.questions[num];
    
    // Display the image if there is one
    if (question.image) {
      $dom.display.innerHTML = '<img src="' + question.image + '" class="question-img"/>';
    }
    // Display the question
    $dom.display.innerHTML +=
        '<p>Q' + (num+1) + ': ' + question.text + '</p>'
      + question.choices.map(function(choice, i) {
         return '<label>'
              +   '<input type="radio" name="' + quiz.name + '" value="' + i + '"/>'
              +   choice.text
              + '</label>';
       }).join('')
      + '<br>';
    
    // Create Submit button
    $submit = document.createElement('button');
    $submit.addEventListener('click', onAnswerSubmit);
    $submit.innerHTML = 'Submit';
    // Add the submit button
    $dom.display.appendChild($submit);
  }
  
  function onAnswerSubmit() {
    // Get the checked radio button
    var selectedChoice = $dom.display.querySelector('input:checked');
    if (!selectedChoice) {
      alert("You need to select an answer");
    } else {
      // If it's correct
      if (quiz.questions[num].choices[selectedChoice.value].correct) {
        score++; // Add 1 point to the score
      }
      num++;
      nextScreen();
    }
  }
  
  function displayEndResult() {
    clearDisplayArea();
    $dom.display.innerHTML = '<p>End of Quiz</p>'
                    + '<p>Congratulations! Your score is: ' + score + '</p>'
                    + '<p>If you scored lower than 2, please keep practising</p>';
  }
  
  function clearDisplayArea() {
    $dom.display.innerHTML = '';
  }

  // The "DOM" (Document Object Model) represents HTML elements
  function initDOM(quiz, $container) {
    // Create frame
    var $frame = document.createElement('div');
    $frame.className = 'frame';
    // Create title
    $title = document.createElement('h3');
    $title.innerHTML = quiz.name;
    // Create display area
    $display = document.createElement('div');
    $display.className = 'display-area';
    // Insert them into each other
    $frame.appendChild($title);
    $frame.appendChild($display);
    $container.appendChild($frame);

    return {
      frame: $frame,
      title: $title,
      display: $display,
      container: $container
    };
  }
}
```

```css
.frame {
    width: 350px;
    background-color: #E9CFEC;
    border: 3px solid #000000;
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 2px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 15px;
}

h3 {
    background: #FAFAFA;
}

.frame label {
  display: block;
}

.frame .display-area {
  padding: 0 .5em .5em;
}

.frame .question-img {
  display: block;
  margin: 1em auto;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Wow that is so much better, Blex, thank you so much.
I got carriesd away with a sample quiz on you tube

Comment: It it also possible to add an image in a question with this code? I tried to change text to image and add image, but is not working

Comment: @pattypool2044 Sure. I updated my answer. I added images to the first quiz (in the `quizzes` variable). And in the `displayQuestion` function, I added an `if` statement to display an image if there is one. I've also added some styles in the CSS to let the frame expand in height, and not let the image get too big.

Comment: I see what I did wrong. I did not add it as an IF Statement. Thank you soooooo much, I have learned a lot with your help :) I am very very gratefull. :)